# how to pass parameters in promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am really stuck with passing values between promises, I wonder if I can get a help here.
I have a CustomerController calling methods in CustomerRepo

```
let getCustomers = customerRepo.getCustomers(req.query.offset, req.query.return);
let getProfiles  = customerRepo.getProfiles(rows);

getCustomers
   .then(function (rows) {
        console.log(rows[0]);
    })
    .then(getProfiles)
```

I do not know how to pass rows (array of customers) to getProfiles so I can populate the customers object with profiles.
Here is the code in CustomerRepo -

```
var getCustomers = function (offset, _return) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var sqlString = 'call qsel_customers' + '(' + offset + ',' + _return + ')';
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        connection.query(sqlString, function (err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else
                resolve(rows);
            connection.release();

        });
        connection.on('error', function (err) {
            res.json({"code": 100, "status": "Error in connection database"});
        });
    });

  });
}
```

and for getProfiles

```
 var getProfiles = function (rows) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     console.log(rows);
  }
}
```

I get rows undefined. Also please could someone suggest how can I extract the db mysql connection code into a dbConnect.js, to avoid code repetition.

Comment: Instead of `.then(getProfiles)` do `.then(function() {getProfiles(...)})`

Comment: @marekful you mean this .then(function() {getProfiles(rows)}) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert in Promises but i don't think that it is good idea to put `pool.getConnection` inside your `getCustomers` promise.
It looks like another promise and should be chained rather then combined.

Getting back to your main quersion. You can do this

```
getCustomers
.then(function (rows) {
 return getProfiles(rows); 
})
.then(function() {
console.log('get profiles resolved');
});
```

and

```
 var getProfiles = function (rows) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     resolve(rows);
     console.log('other log of rows:' + rows);
  }
}
```

**EDITED:**

```
let getCustomers = customerRepo.getCustomers(req.query.offset, req.query.return);
let getProfiles  = customerRepo.getProfiles;

getCustomers
   .then(function (rows) {
        return getProfiles(rows);
    })
    .then(function(rows) {
     console.log('rows number ' + rows);
     console.log('get profiles resolved');           
     );
```

Answer (score 2):

Promise denotes the computation that may fail or not at some point in time. Therefore, in order to create a Promise you do:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // here you decide when the computation fails and when succeeds
  resolve(1) // success
  reject('error') // failed
})
```

Promise has a method (a swiss-knife, indeed) called `then`. It takes a function ƒ of one argument. Now, the magic of ƒ looks like this:

- if ƒ returns simple value (string, number, array, etc) then it will wrap it in a new Promise and return it. The signature is `then : Promise[a] -> (a -> b) -> Promise[b]`. Therefore, say you have a function ∂ that returns a Promise of a number and ƒ takes a number and adds "!" to it, you and get this number, pass it to ƒ using `then` and end up with a new Promise:

  ƒ.then(n => n + '!') // Promise[String]
- if ƒ returns a Promise, then `then` will "extract" the value if this Promise, pass it to ∂ and return a new Promise with the result. In pseudocode:

  ƒ.then(n => Promise(n + '!')) // Promise[String]

Okay, `then` returns a Promise. Well, let's design the code:

```
let getCustomers = () => Promise.resolve([ {}, {}, {} ])
// assume myApi.getProfile takes a Customer and returns a Profile
let getProfiles = (customers) => customers.map(myApi.getProfile)
getCustomers().then(getProfiles).then(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: I see why I get confused, especially for a beginner, there are so many ways of doing the same thing. I wish I can find a detailed blog/tut to go through it. Anyway thanks Ivan

Comment: Yes, this is actually the problem of a bad design: the one method for mapping, chaining, error mapping... I hope, my post was helpful.

Comment: Here's by the way a good tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201612092212543850361

Comment: Thanks Ivan, yes very helpful

Answer (score 1):

When chaining Promises, you have to return a Promise resolved with the value you're passing from the upstream function in order to use it in the downstream function.

```
getCustomers
  .then(function (rows) {
    console.log(rows[0]);
    return Promise.resolve(rows[0]);
  })
  .then(function(firstRow) {
    console.log("The first row's id is " + firstRow.id);
    return Promise.resolve(firstRow);
  })
  .then(getProfiles);
```

If you need to do asynchronous work in one of the functions, return a new Promise and invoke the resolve/reject functions as appropriate in the asynchronous callback. `Promise.resolve()` is a shortcut you can use if you're not doing anything asynchronously; it simply returns a Promise object resolved with the value it's passed.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, I really find coding promises very confusing and would like to settle down on a version of  Promise code that works. Is there a way to abstract sql queries into a promise? especially in chaining multiple queries?

Comment: You are probably better off `yield`ing multiple queries with [co](https://github.com/tj/co), assuming you're using ES6.